# Moving mod_rewrite from httpd.conf to .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I think this may be relatively straight forward. I have a rewrite rule that basically removes the .php from the URL but it isn't a bog standard URL. It works fine in my httpd.conf file but not if I move to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php/$1/$2 [QSA]
```

Now I know in .htaccess you have to remove the section that references the current directory but I haven't had any luck yet, any thoughts/suggestions/solutions most welcome.

Comment: Did you specify `AllowOverride All` in your virtualhost directory definition ?

Comment: Hi Pierre-Olivier, yes I did. The .htaccess file being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs passed to `RewriteRule` never have an initial slash. Remove it. And the one in the replacement, since [they're filesystem paths](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

> ```
> Given Rule                                      Resulting Substitution
> ----------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------
> ^localpath(.*) otherpath$1                      /somepath/otherpath/pathinfo
> ```

Comment: Hi Ignacio

Thanks for the reply, found a work-around in the meantime but still would like to get to the bottom of this. 

I have been through many versions of this both with and without the slash. The thing that niggled me was removing the .php on index, I made the .htaccess local to the filename but I still needed to reference itself within that directory.